# Reduce size of git repository on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

After few months of (commit & push) for my project, the size of the repository gets increased gradually on Bitbucket! it's about 1 GB, I tried to remove some databases folders that are not important to be added.
After searching I found most of suggestions is proposing :

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder/subfolder' HEAD
```

After removing few folders I push the change to the repository by -- force, as

```
git push origin master --force
```

I finally found that the repository gets larger every time I use those commands !!. 
Visibly, the repository gets larger 2.5 GB!!

Any suggestion please ?

**EDIT**
Depending on the suggestion below, I tried the following commands
  (for all large files)

> git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch
>   $files" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

(remove the temporary history git-filter-branch otherwise leaves behind for a long time)

> rm -rf .git/refs/original/

```
git reflog expire --all
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

But the folder .git/objects has still a big size !!!!

Comment: Do you have other branches and/or tags than `master` (presumably `HEAD` points to `master` here...)?

Comment: Try `git gc --prune=now` on your local repo, git keeps references to your previous changes. If your local repo get's smaller it will eventually get smaller on bitbucket to.

Comment: @torek: Yes I have branches and tags

Comment: @willem-dhaeseleer: I tried git gc --prune=now, it reduces a bit, about 2 GB right now!

Comment: my question is edited

Answer (score 8):

OK, given your answer to your comment, we can now say what happened.

What `git filter-branch` does is to *copy* (some or all of) your commits to new ones, then update the references.  This means your repository gets *bigger* (not smaller), at least initially.

The commits that are copied are those reachable via the references given.  In this case, the reference you gave is `HEAD` (which git turns into "your current branch", probably `master`, but whatever your current branch was at the time of the `filter-branch` command).  If (and only if) the new copy is precisely, bit-for-bit identical to the original, then it actually *is* the original and there is no actual copy made (the original is reused instead).  However, as soon as you make any change—such as removing `folder/subfolder`, from that point on these really are copies.

The copied stuff is, in this case, smaller, because you've removed some items.  (It's generally not very much smaller since git compresses items pretty well.)  But you're still adding more stuff to the repository: new commits, which refer to new trees, which—fortunately—refer to the same old blobs (file objects) as before, just slightly fewer of them this time (the objects for the `folder/subfolder` files are still in the repository, but the copied commits and tree-objects no longer refer to them).

Pictorially, at this point in the `filter-branch` process, we now have both the old commits:

```
R--o--o---o--o   <-- master
    \    /
     o--o        <-- feature
```

and the new ones (I'll assume `folder/subfolder` appeared in the original root commit `R` so that we have a copy `R'` here):

```
R'-o'-o'--o'-o'
    \    /
     o'-o'
```

What `filter-branch` does now, at the end of the copying process, is re-point *some* references (branch and tag names, mainly).  The ones it re-points are the ones you tell it to, by mentioning them as what the documentation calls "positive references".  In this case, if you were on `master` (i.e., `HEAD` was another name for `master`), the single positive reference you gave is `master` ... so that's *all* `filter-branch` re-points.  It also makes backup references whose name starts with `refs/original/`.  This means you now have the following commits:

```
R--o--o---o--o   <-- refs/original/refs/heads/master
    \    /
     o--o        <-- feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'
```

Note that `feature` still points to all the *old* (not-copied) commits, so that even if / after you get rid of any `refs/original/` references, git will retain all the still-referenced commits across any garbage-collect activity, giving:

```
R--o
    \
     o--o        <-- feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'
```

To get `filter-branch` to update *all* the references, you need to name them all.  An easy way to do that is to use `--all`, which quite literally names all references.  In this case, the initial "after" picture looks like this instead:

```
R--o--o---o--o   <-- refs/original/refs/heads/master
    \    /
     o--o        <-- refs/original/refs/heads/feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'       <-- feature
```

Now if you erase all the `refs/original/` references, all the old commits become unreferenced and can get garbage-collected.  Well, that is, they do *unless there are tags pointing to them.*

For tag references, `filter-branch` only updates them in any way if you supply a `--tag-name-filter`.  Usually you want `--tag-name-filter cat`, which keeps the tag names unchanged, but makes `filter-branch` point them to the newly copied commits.  That way you don't hang on to the old commits: the whole point of the exercise is to make everything use the new copies, and throw away the old copies, so that the big-file objects can be garbage-collected.

---

Putting this all together, instead of:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder/subfolder'
```

you can use:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder/subfolder' \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

(You don't need the backslash-newline sequence; I put that in just to make the line fit better on stackoverflow.  Note that `--tree-filter` is very slow: for this particular case it is much faster to use `--index-filter`.  The index filter command here would be `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r folder/subfolder`.)

Note also that you need to do all this on (a copy of) the *original* repository (you did keep a backup, right?).  (If you did not keep a backup, the `refs/originals/` may be your salvation.)

---

Edit: OK, so you did some `filter-branch`-ing, and you did something that deleted any `refs/originals/`. (In my experiment on a temp repo, running `git filter-branch` on `HEAD` used whatever branch I was on as the branch that was re-pointed, and made an "originals" copy of the previous value.)  There are no backups of the repository.  Now what?

Well, as a first step, **make a backup now**.  This way, if things get any worse, you can at least get back to "only slightly bad".  To make a backup of the repo, you can simply clone it (or: clone it, then call the original the "backup", then begin working on the clone).  For future reference, since `git filter-branch` can be quite destructive, it's usually wise to start by doing this backing-up process.  (Also, I'll note that a clone on bitbucket, when not yet `push`ed-to, would serve.  Unfortunately you did a `push`.  Perhaps bitbucket can retrieve an earlier version of the repository from some backups or snapshots of their own.)

Next, let's note a peculiarity of commits and their SHA-1 "true names", that I mentioned earlier.  The SHA-1 name of a commit is a cryptographic checksum of its contents.  Let's take a look at a sample commit in git's own source tree (trimmed down a bit just for length, and email addresses whacked to foil harvesters):

```
$ git cat-file -p 5de7f500c13c8158696a68d86da1030313ddaf69
tree 73eee5d136d2b00c623c3fceceffab85c9e9b47e
parent c4ad00f8ccb59a0ae0735e8e32b203d4bd835616
author Jeff King <peff peff.net> 1405233728 -0400
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1406567673 -0700

alloc: factor out commit index

We keep a static counter to set the commit index on newly
allocated objects. However, since we also need to set the
[snip]
```

Here, we can see that the contents of this commit (whose "true name" is `5de7f50...`) start with a `tree` and another SHA-1, a `parent` and another SHA-1, an `author` and `committer`, then a blank line followed by the commit message text.

If you look at a `tree` you'll see that it contains the "true names" (SHA-1 values) of sub-trees (sub-directories) and file objects ("blobs", in git terminology) along with their modes—really, just whether the blob should have execute permission set, or not—and their names within the directory.  For instance, the first line of the above `tree` is:

```
100644 blob 5e98806c6cc246acef5f539ae191710a0c06ad3f    .gitattributes
```

which means that the repository object `5e98806...` should be extracted, put in a file named `.gitattributes`, and set non-executable.

If I ask git to make a *new* commit, and set up, as its contents:

- the same tree (`73eee5d...`)
- the same parent (`c4ad00f...`)
- the same author and committer
- and the same blank line and message

then when I get git to write that commit to the repository, it will generate the same "true name" `5de7f50...`.  In other words, it literally is the same commit: it's already in the repository and `git commit-tree` will just give me back the existing ID.  While it's a bit tricky to set all this up, that's exactly what `git filter-branch` ends up doing: it extracts the original commit, applies your filters, sets up everything, and then does a `git commit-tree`.

#### What this means for you

On your original repo, you ran a `git filter-branch` command that copied commits to new, modified commits (with different `tree`s and hence, at some point, different true names which led to different parent IDs in subsequent commits, and so on).  However, if you copy those copied commits by applying a filter that this time *does nothing*, then the new `tree` objects will be *the same* as the old ones.  If the new *parent* is the same, and the author, committer, and message also all remain the same, the new commit-ID for the copy will be *the same* as the old ID.

That is, these *new* copies are not copies after all, they're just the originals again!

Any other commits—those that were *not* copied in the first pass—do get copied, and hence have different IDs.

Here's where things get tricky.

**If your current repository looks like this** (graphically speaking):

```
R--o--o---o--o   <-- xxx [needs a name so that filter-branch will process it]
    \    /
     o--o        <-- feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'
```

and we apply a new `filter-branch` to *all* references (or even "all but `master`") in such a way that it generates the same trees this time, it will copy `R` again and the new tree will match that for `R'`, so the copy will actually *be* `R'`.  Then it will copy the first post-`R` node, make the same changes, and the copy will actually *be* the first post-`R'`, `o'` node.  This will repeat for all nodes, possibly even including `R'` and all the `o'`s.  If `filter-branch` copies `R'`, the resulting copy will just be `R'` again, though, because "remove nonexistent directory" makes no change: our filter does nothing to these particular commits.

Finally, filter-branch will move the labels, leaving the `refs/originals/` versions behind:

```
R--o--o---o--o   <-- refs/originals/refs/xxx
    \    /
     o--o        <-- refs/originals/refs/feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master, xxx
    \    /
     o'-o'       <-- feature
```

This is, in fact, the desired outcome.

**What if the repository looks more like this?**  That is, what if there is no `xxx` or similar label pointing to the original (pre-filtering) `master`, so that you have this:

```
R--o
    \
     o--o        <-- feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'
```

The `filter-branch` script will still copy `R` and the result will still be `R'`.  Then it will copy the first `o` node and the result will still be the first `o'` node, and so on.  It won't copy the now-deleted nodes, but it won't have to: we already have those, reachable via the branch-name `master`.  As before, `filter-branch` may copy `R'` and the various `o'` nodes, but this is OK, as the filter will do nothing so that the copies are really just the originals after all.

Last, `filter-branch` will, as usual, update the references:

```
R--o
    \
     o--o        <-- refs/originals/refs/feature

R'-o'-o'--o'-o'  <-- master
    \    /
     o'-o'       <-- feature
```

---

The key that makes this all work is that the filter leaves already-modified commits untouched, so that their second "copies" are just the first-copies again.<sup>1</sup>

Once everything is done, you can do the same shrinking described in [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to ditch the `refs/originals/` names and garbage-collect the now-unreferenced objects.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you had been using a filter that is not as easily repeated (e.g., one that makes new commits with "the current time" as their time-stamps), you would really need an untouched original repository, or those `refs/originals/` references (either one would suffice to keep an "original copy" around).

Comment: I understand better now. 
Then the final command that I need to use it is:
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r folder/subfolder' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
is that correct ?

i did not understand what do you mean by this :(If you did not keep a backup, the refs/originals/ may be your salvation).

Comment: In my case I checked ref/original on local disk it is empty !!

Comment: Well, consider what your repo looks like if you did *one* filter-branch (which made copies of commits but only re-pointed `master`) and then you do a *new* filter-branch (which makes copies of all commits, including the copies of the originals).  With some care and/or luck it can all be made to work, but it's easier to restore the old `master` and discard all the first-run copies.  Now you're back to all-originals.  How do you restore the old `master`?  One way is to use the refs/originals/refs/master ref.

Comment: thank you, but could you help me how to restore the old master, actually I executed (git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf folder/subfolder' HEAD) many times, should I use :
git reset --hard origin/master
or something else ?
for me on local disk  refs/originals/ is empty !!, would you please put the complete command to restore the old stuff ?

Comment: It's probably too late to get it back as it was, if you did not save a backup.  (Remember to consider other possible backups, such as a Time Machine backup on a Mac, another clone of the repo somewhere you did not push to, etc.)  However, we can make use of other properties of git to recover or construct the final target version.  I don't have time to write this right now though (perhaps later today).  As a general rule, before fussing with `filter-branch` you should clone the repo, and do the fussing with only one copy, since `filter-branch` can make quite a mess.

Comment: I did a backup by clone somewhere.
Actually I checked the project folder on local disk and I found that the big size comes from this folder: .git/objects/pack. Is it safe if i delete it? or to shrink it ??

Comment: The `pack` files are where the (packed) objects are stored.  In other words, that's where git keeps all your files, trees, commits, etc.  If you remove those you're removing all your files!